# How to shim a class that is called more than once in the tested function using microsoft fakes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

Suppose I got a class and it has a GetList() like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> GetList(string para);
}
```

And the tested function is like

```
public ResultType TestedFunc()
{
    if( GetList("condition").count() == 1 )
    {
        //do arrange business
        if( GetList("same condition as above".count() == 2 )
        {
            //do core business
        }
        else
        {
            return ResultType;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return ResultType
    }
}
```

In my test method I use ShimFoo.AllInstance.GetList to shim the GetList(). Regardless of the weird business and call logic, My question is how can I have the first GetList() call and the second GetListh() call return different results, say lists that respectively contains one and two entity.

For further discussion, I want to know the difference between the so called "fake" and what we already have - "mock"

I have read the three official article about MS Fake:

1.[Isolating Code Under Test with Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx)

2.[Using stubs to isolate parts of your application from each other for unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549174(v=vs.110).aspx)

3.[Using shims to isolate your application from other assemblies for unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176(v=vs.110).aspx)

but I haven't yet found the guide that can do what I what as described above.

I've learned that behavior verification can be done on mock test, there are lot of framework that can achieve this(such as google mock). I can define how the mock class work when it is first/second/third time to be called, I can set a sequence to strictly limit the mock class. I wonder if MS Fakes can do the same thing.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply keep a call counter by capturing a `int` variable when setting up the Shim.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using(ShimsContext.Create()) {
        int counter = 0; // define the int outside of the delegate to capture it's value between calls.

        ShimFoo sfoo = new ShimFoo();
        sfoo.GetListString = (param) =>
        {
            List<Bar> result = null;
            switch (counter)
            {
                case 0: // First call
                    result = new Bar[] { }.ToList();
                    break;
                case 1: // Second call
                    result = new Bar[] { new Bar() }.ToList();
                    break;
            }
            counter++;
            return result;
        };
        Foo foo = sfoo.Instance;

        Assert.AreEqual(0, foo.GetList("first").Count(), "First");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, foo.GetList("second").Count(), "Second");
        Assert.IsNull(foo.GetList("third"), "Third");
    }
}
```

Or you can check the parameter being passed and adjust the result accordingly.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using(ShimsContext.Create()) {
        ShimFoo sfoo = new ShimFoo();
        sfoo.GetListString = (param) =>
        {
            List<Bar> result = null;
            switch (param)
            {
                case "first": // First call
                    result = new Bar[] { }.ToList();
                    break;
                case "second": // Second call
                    result = new Bar[] { new Bar() }.ToList();
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        };
        Foo foo = sfoo.Instance;

        Assert.AreEqual(0, foo.GetList("first").Count(), "First");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, foo.GetList("second").Count(), "Second");
        Assert.IsNull(foo.GetList("third"), "Third");
    }
}
```

Comment: The two calls actually have the same param, I need to check if there exists a entity in db so i get first, then i insert one and get it, so sln two seems weak.

Comment: How do i count that int? would you please give me an example?

Comment: Alternatively, you could keep a `List<Bar>` instead of a counter, and have multiple method shims update it as part of the tests. It does require quire a bit of bookkeeping to pull that off, but it would certainly work.

Comment: So I get your point, using shims is just like re-define the function. Seems that I get some work to do on delegate. Anyway your answer solves my problems, thanks :)